# how to render tenjin_template in django1.6

Tags: django-templates

Here is my view which renders my tenjin_template in Django. It gives me an error

> **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Here is the code

```
 def get(self, request):
 voucher_request = Voucher.objects.all()
 context = RequestContext(request, {
 'voucher_request': voucher_request,
 })        
 return self.tenjin_response("billing/voucher.html", context)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked down the error using '>'.  And the code is marked down using 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of above question:

```
def get(self,*args, **kwargs):
        voucher_request = Voucher.objects.all()
        if voucher_request == MANAGE_RAISE:
            return self.permission_exception()
        context = {
            'voucher_request': Voucher.objects.all(),
        }        
        return self.tenjin_response("billing/voucher.html", context)
```